# how to show null when use iferror excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there anyone know how to show null when use iferror in excel?
i use multiple in iferror, but it shows 0, not show zero space or null;

screenshot is like this :
[image]

i want the result is like this,
[image]

Comment: `IFERROR()` is meant to treat errors, and since your multiplication will never result in an error, youll see a zero. Note that excel will treat empty cells as zero in such occasions. So try: `=IF(AND(E5<>"",F5<>""),E5*F5,"")` or `=IF(COUNT(A1:B1)=2,A1*B1,"")`.

Comment: `=IF(OR(E5="",F5=""),"",E5*F5)` or `=IF(COUNTBLANK(E5:F5)=2,"",E5*F5)`

Comment: @AdamTheory there are lot of alternatives, 1.) `=IF(COUNTA(E5:F5)=2,E5*F5,"")` , 2.) `=IF(COUNTBLANK(E5:F5)=1,"",E5*F5)` in the above comment instead of 2 it should be 1

Answer (score 1):

I suppose if you need to use the `=IFERROR` formula, you could rely on the div#0 error by multiplying and dividing by itself:

```
=IFERROR(E5*F5*F5/F5," ")
```

This will give an error if F5 is 0.